# Rails reuse object to save memory in bulk import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memory

I'm currently using SmarterCSV to do bulk CSV import via MongoDB's `upsert` commands. I have the following code excerpt:

```
 SmarterCSV.process(csv, csv_options) do |chunk|
    chunk.each do |row|
      #creates a temporary user to store the object
      user = User.new 
      #converts row info to populate user object
      #creates an array of commands that can be executed by MongoDB via user.as_document
              updates << {:q => {:email => user.email},
                          :u => {:$set => user.as_document},
                          :multi => false,
                          :upsert => true}
      user = nil
    end
  end
```

However, I'm noticing that the memory usage keeps growing as the Garbage Collection (using Rails 3.2.14 & Ruby 2.0.0p353) doesn't seem to clear the temporary `user` objects fast enough.

So I tried to create `user = User.new` outside of the `SmarterCSV` process (see below) and reuse the `user` object within the process. This saves memory. However, `user.as_document` would overwrite previous elements in the `updates` array on each iteration. I was able to solve the problem by using `user.as_document.to_json`, but that doesn't set any of `User`'s relationship correctly. For example, instead of saving a BSON reference for an relation's id, it only saves the id in string format.

Any ideas? Is there a way that I can optimize the bulk import process?

```
 user = User.new 
 SmarterCSV.process(csv, csv_options) do |chunk|
    chunk.each do |row|
      #creates a temporary user to store the object
      #converts row info to populate & reuse user object
      #creates an array of commands that can be executed by MongoDB via user.as_document.to_json
              updates << {:q => {:email => user.email},
                          :u => {:$set => user.as_document.to_json},
                          :multi => false,
                          :upsert => true}
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where exactly are you assigning row to user?

Comment: I'm reusing the user object before adding it to the updates array

Answer (score 0):

I ended fixing this by using 'user.as_document.deep_dup'